# How to select correct sound output device in the NAudio, after added/removed a sound device?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, audio, naudio

I am using the NAudio library to test audio output devices on Win based PC.
Now, when I launch app, everything works fine, until I add, or remove new audio device - such as stick/remove headphones to the headphones audio jack.
Since this moment on, the static list of devices: `var devs = NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut.Devices` gets updated.
I look at the devices names, determine its index - in the `IEnumerable devs`
 but when I set the desired device number:

```
_nAudioSoundOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut() { DeviceNumber = wantedDeviceIndex};
```

then Init and play:

```
_nAudioSoundOut.Init(_mp3Reader);    
_nAudioSoundOut.Play();
```

then some of the devices seem to be confused (swapped).
Is there something I missed, doing wrong, or did I spot a bug ?

Yes, I made sure, I index proper device by its name, and yes I did consider the -1 to the index, as -1st is the default windows device, and first in the list is actually 0.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

The problem was, I used the static device list `devs = NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut.Devices`
which does not maintain same order as devices in NAudio.Wave.WaveOut.. Strange and confusing.
Hence, this is what I had to do to get fixed..

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < NAudio.Wave.WaveOut.DeviceCount; ++idx)
    {
        string devName = NAudio.Wave.WaveOut.GetCapabilities(idx).ProductName;
        if (devName.Contains(SelectedSpeaker.DisplayName) || SelectedSpeaker.DisplayName.Contains(devName))
        {
            indexSelectedSpeaker = idx;
            break;
        }
    }
```